# How come full throttle is meaning full speed instead of the opposite?

Tags: throttle, terminology

I am stumbling about full throttle. To throttle usually means to brake down or slowing down. Technically it is a flap which is reducing the air delivery which is important for the combustion process.
So my natural understanding of full throttle would mean no air, no combustion, no power but it is used contradictional. How does this come?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a language use question and not about mechanics. It would probably be better on the English usage SE.

Comment: Full throttle equates to full power aka pedal to the metal aka give it the beanz etc

Comment: It is only a flap in an engine with a carburettor, not one with fuel injection.

Comment: @GdD - I disagree. It has to do with how an engine runs and to understand why. It's like when someone needs understanding of the difference between engaging/disengaging a clutch. Usually, pressing a pedal would mean to "engage" something, but it's the opposite of those things. This question has to do with the overall understanding of how a vehicle works, so in my non-mod view, should still stand.

Comment: I considered to post it into English stack exchange, however I decided there is more audience related to it here even if probably more language related, I think it is motor related slang.

Comment: Excellent questions. I have wondered this many times myself. Now I know the answer!

Comment: @Chenmunka to be pedantic, a fuel injected engine does indeed have a 'flap' (butterfly valve) in the throttle body

Comment: Same reason you park in the driveway and drive on the parkway.

Comment: @AaronLavers:  Of course you're right - my mistake.  I have a lot more experience of taking carburettors apart than injection systems.

Comment: @GdD the question becomes language related only when you know the answer. And the answer is still mechanics-related.

Comment: You're *opening* the throttle to full.

Comment: Road vehicles have the fuel/air supply closed by a spring by default, and opened by an accelerator, so if the control breaks, they stop. Aero engines have the fuel/air supply opened by a spring by default, and closed by a throttle, so if the control breaks, they continue to fly (at full power) instead of plummeting. An aircraft in that situation can be controlled for landing by juggling with the ignition switches.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It is the difference between the verb and the noun.

You are right, the verb *throttle* means to restrict - to slow down flow, therefore *to fully throttle* is to stop the engine.

However, the noun *throttle* refers to the mechanism.  Thus setting a *full throttle* means that the mechanism is set to fully open - unrestricted.

Don't ever expect the English language to be too logical.
The question has already been covered on  [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).
e.g. https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/169310/4376 and https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/213233/4376

Comment: Nice examples! +1 one for a great, understandable answer, plus using resources on other stacks to make your point. Noice!

Comment: Indeed. Same reason people often call it the "gas pedal" even though it's really the "air pedal".

Comment: I agree this question belongs on language stack.  This answer is great, and it hinges on nouns and verbs, not mechanics.

Comment: @whatsisname  Well, air is a gas.  ;)

Comment: Languages (English included) have their own logic that is not always obvious.

Comment: @whatsisname How can we have logic on a world where people talk about the sun setting, but really it is the horizon rising?

Comment: @fraxinus Languages have semantics and meaning... I don't think we can properly call the informal miasma of rules governing English to be anything you would call "logic", however.

Comment: Interestingly, in some romance languages (at least Italian, Catalan and Spanish) the noun for throttle comes from the verb meaning to accelerate instead of to restrict, and this particular paradox doesn't happen.

Comment: @user3067860  " ... rising ..." -> +10 :-)

Comment: @user3067860, good point, but the horizon isn't rising either. If you don't change locations, the horizon never changes altitude WRT to you. The only real thing we can say is something to the effect that the earth is changing orientation to prevent you from seeing the sun. And that ignores the angle of refraction of the atmosphere. Of course, all of this is off topic to this Stack. Lol.

Comment: Neither of those two linked questions seem to address the difference between throttling something, and what "full throttle" on a motor vehicle.

Comment: @Pere  It can also be called the "accelerator" in English.  In fact, calling the foot-pedal version the "throttle" seems to be somewhat on the decline, although it remains the common term when talking about a hand-lever control.